# Collapse properly parent navigation controller from child scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I have a Navigation controller with inside a Page controller of View controllers (with a collection view inside).

When I scroll the collection, the navigation bar must shrink. But when it's in the default position and I scroll it down, something strange happens (see the gif).

[image: scroll problem]

I created a delegate that tells the main controller which is the offset of scrollview.

```
//CollectionViewController
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        delegate?.didScrollViewPosition(yOffset: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
```

and

```
//Navigation view controller
extension ContainerViewController: CollectionViewControllerDelegate {

    func didScrollViewPosition(yOffset: CGFloat) {
       if (yOffset <= 52 && yOffset >= 0) {
            let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 96 - yOffset)
       }
    }   

}
```

Comment: I think you need else statement as your case handle values between 0...52 ,,,what about if it exceeds ??

Comment: I will try it, thanks

Comment: @Sh_Khan more or less the same problem: if (yOffset <= 0) {
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 96)
 } else if (yOffset > 0 && yOffset <= 52) {
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 96 - yOffset)
 } else if (yOffset > 52) {
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 44) }

Comment: Resolved: if I leave in the first and last condition, empty, it works perfectly.
If you enter the answer, I accept it, thank you!